# Efficient way to sum specific row groupings in R

Tags: r, matrix

As a quick example, I have a `3x5` matrix

```
mat <- matrix(rep(seq(5),3),nrow=3,byrow = T)
```

I'd like to sum across elements in each row based on a specific grouping defined by `map.list`, which has the same number of main elements as the `nrow(mat)`. It could look something like this:

```
map.list <- list(list(c(1,2),c(3,4),5),
             list(c(1,2),3,c(4,5)),
             list(c(1,2),4,5))

> map.list
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 3 4

[[1]][[3]]
[1] 5


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 3

[[2]][[3]]
[1] 4 5


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[3]][[2]]
[1] 3

[[3]][[3]]
[1] 5
```

This means that for the first row of `mat`, we would sum `1+2=3`, `3+4=7`, and `5=5` to create the first row of a new matrix `mat2`. We proceed similarly for the other two elements, corresponding to rows 2 and 3 of the new matrix.

```
> mat2
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    7    5
[2,]    3    3    9
[3,]    3    3    5
```

How could I efficiently create this? Potentially, I'd have a `mat` that has many rows and many columns.

Comment: I think the last value would be 5.  You haven't changed the value of input dataset of `map.list`

Answer (score 0):

We can do

```
t(sapply(seq_len(nrow(mat)), function(i) sapply(map.list[[i]],function(j) sum(mat[i, j]))))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    3    7    5
#[2,]    3    3    9
#[3,]    3    3    5
```

---

Or another option is

```
library(reshape2)
dM <- melt(map.list)[, 3:1]
m1 <- sapply(split(mat[as.matrix(dM[-2])],
       interaction(dM[1:2], drop = TRUE, lex.order = TRUE)), sum)
matrix(m1, 3, 3, byrow=TRUE)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    3    7    5
#[2,]    3    3    9
#[3,]    3    3    5
```

#### data

```
map.list <- list(list(c(1,2),c(3,4),5),
         list(c(1,2),3,c(4,5)),
         list(c(1,2),3,5))
```